# Galois cohomology of $GL_n(E^s \hat{\otimes} R)$

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations, galois-cohomology

Let $E= \mathbb{F}_p(\!(u)\!)$ and write $E^s$ for a separable closure. Write $G_E = \mathrm{Gal}(E^s/E)$ for the absolute galois group of $E$. Let $R$ be a noetherian $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra and write $E^s \hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb{F}_p} R= \mathrm{dirlim}_{E \subseteq K \subseteq E^s \text{ finite}}(K \hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb{F}_p}R)$ where $K \hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb{F}_p} R$ is the $u$-adic completion of $K \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p}R$.

Is it true that $H^1(G_E, \mathrm{GL}_n(E^s \hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb{F}_p} R))=\{1\}$? I think if $R= \mathbb{F}_p$, this is just a version of Hilbert '90; but I sadly know virtually nothing about group cohomology, so I don't see if in this more general context it still holds true.

Comment: In case it may be of some help, by etale descent for vector bundles the meaning of such vanishing is exactly that if $M$ is a rank-$n$ vector bundle over the $E$-algebra $A := R[\![u]\!][1/u]$ and $M \otimes_E K$ is free over $A \otimes_E K$ for *some* finite Galois extension $K/E$ then $M$ is free as an $A$-module. (So for $R$ a field the vanishing is easy because then $A$ is a field.)

Comment: Does this mean that if $V$ is a free $G_E$ representation with coefficients in $R$, that then $((E^s \hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb{F}_p} R) \otimes_R V)^{G_E}$ is locally free?

Comment: No, such local freeness over $A$ is automatic. Your setup treats $R$ discretely, so the only natural meaning I see for the phrase "free $G_E$-representation with coefficients in $R$ is as a discrete $G_E$-action on a finitely generated free $R$-module $V$", in which case some open normal subgroup $G_K$ acts trivially. But then the $G_K$-invariants of $(E_s\widehat{\otimes}_{\mathbf{F}_p} R) \otimes_R V$ coincide with $K\widehat{\otimes}_{{\mathbf{F}}_p}V$ (with its ${\rm{Gal}}(K/E)$-action), a free module over $K \otimes_E A$. Etale descent for modules then gives the desired local freeness.